# What does 꿀잠각 mean?

Tags: meaning, word-origin

Based on the Google results of *꿀잠각 뜻*, there is no relevant page to explain how it is. But the search result shows it is the word that people actually use, with the hashtag #꿀잠각 seen on Instagram.

I think it is a new word (신조어) but what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. 꿀잠

`꿀잠`--literally "honey sleep"--is a trendy way of saying for "a good sleep".

### 2. 각 (角)

`각(角)` is an abbreviation of `각도(角度)` meaning "an angle".
Another translation for that is "expectation", "feeling lucky" or "a good situation" that is going to be a big hit - which is a gamblers vocabulary common among billiards and LOL(League of Legends)-like game's players. Such meaning of this word is derived from what people call "the angle" in billiards--the angle that's going to make the three-cushion.

E.g.

- `포각` - An angle of an artillery
- `우승각` - An angle (situation) where someone is about to win a league/tournament
- `킬각` - An angle someone is about to kill the opponent - "Lethal"
- `꿀잠각` - An angle someone is going to sleep well - "About to sleep well"

Verbs

- `~각을 잰다` - Measure the angle (of something)
- `~각을 낸다` - Make an angle (of something) / Get an advantage (of something)
- `~각을 본다` - Have an eye on (something)
- `~각 나온다` - It is obvious that ~ / It will hit ~ / It's gonna be good.
- `~각 잡다` - Got the hang of it

Comment: 그리고 "당구 용어"라는 개념을 이해하실지 모르겠는데 이건 한국에만 있는 건가 싶네요. 당구에서 쓰는 말은 거의 다른 세상 언어라고 할 정도로 어휘가 다양하고 어렵거든요. 구글에 "당구 용어" 검색하거나 [이런 글](https://pann.nate.com/talk/341528811)을 보면 느낌이 옵니다. 무슨무슨 각이라는 것도 원래 당구 용어였던 것으로 기억하는데 인터넷 게임을 통해서 확산되면서 여러가지 상황에서 응용되고 있습니다.

Answer (score 3):

꿀, which means "honey", is often used as a (slang) prefix for something that is good or easy. 잠 is just "sleep". 각, which means "angle", is also a slang word for "opportunity" or "chance". So 꿀잠각 means a good chance to get a good sleep. For example, when you finished some work in a very satisfying way at like 10 pm, you can say that.

Other examples:
꿀잼=꿀+재미 = very fun.
자살각=자살+각 = "chance to suicide", a slang word roughly equivalent to "I fxxked up".